# Identify the processes that executing a .sh created

Tags: shell, unix, grep, ps

I am new to Unix.
How do I find the processes that were created when I execute a agent.sh.

ps -ef | grep agent

Does not return anything.

Thanks,
Kiran

Answer (score 1):

You can easily identify child processes, for instance, using a tool like `pstree` (this is a non-standard program for making human-readable output).

```
 ~ $ pstree -ps "$PPID"
init(1)───tmux(9707)─┬─bash(9708)─┬─bash(9742)───trayer(9743)
                     │            └─weechat-curses(10594)
                     ├─bash(10729)───su(10746)───bash(10752)───vim(10761)
                     ├─bash(10818)───ksh(1748)
                     ├─bash(15133)───pstree(15474)
                     ├─bash(17879)───man(15076)───sh(15079)───sh(15080)───vimmanpager(15084)───vim(15088)
                     ├─bash(17900)───su(17917)───bash(17922)
                     ├─bash(20076)───man(20095)───sh(20098)───sh(20099)───vimmanpager(20103)───vim(20109)
                     ├─bash(20116)───man(20135)───sh(20138)───sh(20139)───vimmanpager(20143)───vim(20147)
                     └─tmux-mem-cpu-lo(15472)
```

If you need the raw data, at least under Linux, you can crawl through `/proc/<pid>/stat` recursively. You can also probably use `ps` but parsing its output isn't something I like to do.

But your question was "can you identify all processes created by a shell". Technically, no. If you use `disown` or run with `nohup`, and especially if the parent process dies, children can become children of `init` and indistinguishable from processes forked from another shell.

The solution in that case is platform-specific. Under Linux you can use [cgroups](http://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/cgroups/cgroups.txt) if you've built support into the kernel. The BSD equivalent I believe is called "jails".

Also if you're trying to track processes as part of a script for reasons other than development and testing, you should use proper [process management](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ProcessManagement). `ps` should never be used in scripts.

Comment: What your script doing? If its not running for longtime or in background then you can't see them in ps command output because it will just run and exit from process.